# CLLocationManager does not call back method in delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, callback, cllocationmanager

CLLocationManager does not call back method:

```
locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
```

after user's permission.

I'm allocating `CLLocationManager` instance in singleton class (sort of manager), assigning delegate to self, all is looking fine, but is not working.

Also I have many multithreading logic in my app, and I think, the problem is a deadlock or some other problem related to multithreading.

How can I reveal what is the problem.

P.S. I have also tried to call

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges;
```

on main thread and this does not help.

Comment: after authorizing, what is returned by [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]?

Comment: I'm not going to call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, but I call startUpdatingLocation and this works perfect, delegate method getting fired

Comment: @PatrickGoley "YES" is returned. But it looks like the CLLocationManager gets frozen for some reason, and therefore is not invoking callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after hours of trying things, I have found this:
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218118/cllocationmanager-delegates-not-working-after-initialization).

The solution is to allocate CLLocationManager on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strong reference to the `CLLocationManager`? It should be a strong property `@property CLLocationManager *myManager;` or an ivar (instance variable) inside your class' implementation. If you are instantiating the `CLLocationManager` inside a function/method, and not assinging any reference, it will be released as soon as you finish that function.

Have a strong reference to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

alloc/init CLocationManager as soon as `viewDidLoad` gets called worked for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
```