# Why my "Allow Location Access" is always turned off when I switch it to on?

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

Inside `Location Services` I allow my App to **always** use location. In viewDidLoad I created a timer which calls my method every 2 seconds:

```
println("---\(locationManager.location)")
```

In the beginning I get `---nil`, but when I go to the settings and change access to **always**, and then get back to the app again, I immediately get:

```
---<+50.06689474,+19.92923662> +/- 165.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 28.05.2015, 13:00:39 Czas środkowoeuropejski letni
```

But once it is printed there is still: `---nil`. Why?

**This is how I setup `locationManager`:**

```
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

in `viewDidLoad()` I call the method:

```
private func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("printLocation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: @donmarkusi I updated the question with some code

Comment: usually you use the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

Comment: yes, I know, I implemented this, but the methods of delegate are not called...

Comment: hard to tell from here. try to debug your code and see if the location manager get deallocated or something... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697730/cllocationmanager-startupdatinglocation-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The answer how to implement CoreLocation framework in the simplest way in Swift is:

1. `import CoreLocation` **in the file when you use it**
2. Add framework to **Link binary with libraries**:

[image]

3. setup `private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` with methods:

   ```
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

       if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }
   }
   ```
4. In `viewDidLoad` setup your `locationManager` property:

   ```
   private func setupLocationManager() {
       locationManager.delegate = self
       locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

       if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }

       if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
           locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
       }
   }
   ```
5. **most important!!!!** Setup your info.plist file with key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and example value: `Turn on your location, we need it:-)`

[image]