# StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method not return location

Tags: ios, swift

In Significant change location service, I've used the method "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" but it returns cached Location only, it doesn't return updated location information.
I've used Swift language.

Comment: You can try the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697730/cllocationmanager-startupdatinglocation-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are keeping a strong reference to your location manager object, please ensure you are calling `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to function well.

**EDIT:**

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/):

> Regardless of which location service you use, location data is
>   reported to your app via the location manager’s associated delegate
>   object. Because it can take several seconds to return an initial
>   location, the location manager typically delivers the previously
>   cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date
>   location data as it becomes available. Therefore it is always a good
>   idea to check the timestamp of any location object before taking any
>   actions. If both location services are enabled simultaneously, they
>   deliver events using the same set of delegate methods.

Wait for some time and ensure you make a physical location change for location manager to return back the right location. Note that Significant Location Changes mode is always slower than the regular one.

Comment: okay.I am using locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() only.but it return cached location only.FYI - i am checking ios simulator.

Comment: Per Apple documentation, getting a cached location is a valid case. Please take a look at my updated post.

Comment: is possible to check in ios simulator?